# Limiting a Comma Count per line in Multiline Richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

```
231,32
23232,11
232,11
3232,11
```

I need help, i've been searching for a while , got stucked on this one. I use richtextbox and i have no idea how to limit the comma character count per line. There should be only one comma perline.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What should happen if there are more than one?

Comment: the user shoudn't be able to press the comma keys in that focused line, something like disabling the comma keys for a while or remove the second comma with empty.string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to handle the RichTextBox's `KeyPressed` event and check if the `,` char was entered. If it was, get the current line and check if it contains a comma and then decide if the `KeyPress` should be handled or not.

```
private void myRTB_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == ',')
    {
       //get the current line and check if contains a comma
       if (myRTB.Lines[myRTB.GetLineFromCharIndex(myRTB.SelectionStart)].Contains(','))
             e.Handled = true; //contains a comma so handle this keypress 
    }
}
```

This doesn't prevent users from copy/pasting text that contains multiple commas per line so you'll have to deal with that accordingly.

Comment: Awesome man !!, I never explore the GetLine thingy, anyway here is the VB.NET version :

'code' If e.KeyChar = "," Then If rtb.Lines(rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(rtb.SelectionStart)).Contains(",") Then
                          e.Handled = True
                     End If
                End If